# ld: Mismatched Data ABI

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

When I am trying to compile a C code in HP-UX I am getting the following error :

```
gcc  -g -O2   -o autocode /disk1/peru-dev/NIKIRATOOLS/FLEX/lib/hpux64/libfl.a grammer.o tokens.o pgen.o javapgen.o  
ld: Mismatched Data ABI. Expected None but found EF_IA_64_ABI64 in file /disk1/peru-dev/NIKIRATOOLS/FLEX/lib/hpux64/libfl.a[libmain.o]
Fatal error.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [autocode] Error 1
```

I am not able to understand this "Mismatched Data ABI" error. Please help me out.

Comment: It looks like you used different options to compile those object files in command line and those in `libfl.a`. If you can, recompiling that `libfl.a` with the same compilation options and try again.

Comment: How can I recompile libfl.a ?

Comment: Or recompiling your source files with proper options to specify the ABI used by `libfl.a`.

Comment: Place ask the offeror of that library for how to recompile it.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -mlp64` - i.e. compile your code in 64bit mode, which matches the compile mode of the `.o` files contained in the `.a`.